# Which Collection framework to sort Objects

Tags: sorting, object, collections, dictionary

Here is a class

```
Class Emp {
      String firstName;
      String lastName;
      int sal;
      -----------
}
```

here I have a list of 100 employees, I want to sort the objects based on salary and first name & last name.
    using collection frame work how can I do this ?
    Its related to how the dictionary works ??

Comment: Do you want to sort on `salary` as `firstName` as `lastName` at the same time (so if salaries are equal, then compare firstNames)? Or do you want to be able to sort on `salary` at this moment, and `lastName` at another moment?

Comment: Which platform is this? Java?

Answer (score 1):

.NET has several collection to do your task.

**List**

You can create a list with all your entities and sort them with the method `Sort`. Example how to sort on salary (assuming the fields are public):

```
List<Emp> empCollection= new List<Emp>
{
    new Emp { sal = 1000, firstName = "Chris", lastName = "Bakker" },
    new Emp { sal = 1500, firstName = "Bea", lastName = "Smith" },
    // etc.
};
empCollection.Sort((a,b) => a.sal.CompareTo(b.sal));
```

Pro's and con's:

- Pro: You resort the collection on another key.
- Con: Although the list is sorted, you cannot search through if faster on a key.

**SortedDictionary**

You could also use a SortedDictionary. A dictionary is a combination of keys and values. The value, in your case, will always be the employee. They key is the element you want the items to be sorted on. Example to sort on first name:

```
SortedDictionary<string, Emp> empCollection= new SortedDictionary<string, Emp>
{
    {"Chris", new Emp { sal = 1000, firstName = "Chris", lastName = "Bakker" }},
    {"Bea", new Emp { sal = 1500, firstName = "Bea", lastName = "Smith" }},
    // etc.
};
```

Pro's and con's:

- Pro: Once the list is sorted, queries by keys are pretty fast.
- Con: You have to add the key seperately which feels like you are adding duplicate data.
- Con: You cannot resort the collection on another key; you would have to create a new dictionary.

**LINQ**

You can use LINQ to create a newly created and sorted list:

```
List<Emp> empCollection= new List<Emp>
{
    new Emp { sal = 1000, firstName = "Chris", lastName = "Bakker" },
    new Emp { sal = 1500, firstName = "Bea", lastName = "Smith" },
    // etc.
};
List<Emp> sortedEmpCollection = empCollection.OrderBy(e => e.lastName).ToList();
```

Pro's and con's:

- Pro: Syntax is easy to understand.
- Con: A newly created list is created every time (more memory management).
- Con: Although the list is sorted, you cannot search through if faster on a key.

Answer (score 0):

Guava is your bet. It helps in easing such monotonous repetitive tasks.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html

http://pratimsc.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/sorting-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have blogged about this a while back [here](http://objectreferncehell.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/dictionary-versus-hashtables/)

It really depends on what you need, but I find that dictionaries are the best in being type safe as well as faster than a normal HashTable. There are however varoious other options out there for Collections. There are Lists and Arraylists (almost no one uses these any longer) to name a few. MSDN has a plethora of examples of each type, but to get performance, it's best that you google around a little and make your own decision because it's not just all about Performance. There is also extensibility and whether or not you will be using complex or primitive types. It seems like in this scenario you are using complex types, but that might not be your overall goal.

Also if you are in need of things like change notification or Lazy loading, you will want to look at things like IObservable collection and IQueryable with is an extension of IEnumerable.

I just noticed that you were most concerned about Sorting. In C#, your best bet is to use IQueryable and use LINQ if you are familiar with it. it's fast with little overhead and will sort anything you have.

Using your class, here is just the tip of what you could do with LINQ

```
List<Emp> guy = new List<Emp>();

guy.Where(x => x.firstName == "George").OrderBy(x => x.lastName);
```

Hope this helps